How to add <meta name="google" content="notranslate"> with Next 14 App Router
With page router can be done using Head component, as per documentation:
https://nextjs.org/learn-pages-router/seo/crawling-and-indexing/metatags
But now seems not possible, and I can´t find nothing in the documentation.
I also found this, but was not able to test, where a StackOverflow user pointed out how the meta tag should contain "value" instead of "content
<meta name="google" content="notranslate"> not working anymore
It should be good to know also how to handle such situation with the actual metadata constant.
I tried to add for example:
export async function generateMetadata({ params: { lng } }) {
  
  const metadata = siteMetadata[lng] || siteMetadata.en;

  return {
    google: "notranslate",
...

with no luck

is this for a specific page or for the whole application?

I've faced the same problem and the other object will help us.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#other
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
  other: {
    google: 'notranslate',
  }
}

It generates the following tags in the <head>.
<title>Create Next App</title>
<meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app">
<meta name="google" content="notranslate">

